# Compare trends Among two Time Series data-set in R OR PostgreSQL

Tags: r, compare, design-patterns, trend

I have two time series data-sets and I would like to compare them based on their pattern.

P29: Data-set 1:

```
 temperature  Data_Time
1   -1.14 2007-09-29 00:01:57
2   -1.12 2007-09-29 00:03:57
3   -1.33 2007-09-29 00:05:57
4   -1.44 2007-09-29 00:07:57
5   -1.54 2007-09-29 00:09:57
6   -1.29 2007-09-29 00:11:57
```

P28: Data-Set 2:

```
  temperature(Float)     Date_Time(time-stamps)
1   -1.89 2007-09-29 00:00:14
2   -1.79 2007-09-29 00:02:14
3   -1.78 2007-09-29 00:04:14
4   -1.66 2007-09-29 00:06:14
5   -1.68 2007-09-29 00:08:14
6   -1.90 2007-09-29 00:10:14
```

Actually, I thought about using ARMA() but I do not know what should I do later in order to compare trends.

Comment: Are you sure you're asking a programming question and not a statistical one?

Comment: @Roman Both, I am looking for solution.